# Session value sets only on page refresh in a single page

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

When the user is logged in session is set and correct data are shown. But when I click on "aboutview", which have a function named "aboutView()", previously logged in user's data are shown.When I refresh the page it will show the correct data of current logged in user.

Please check and correct the errors.

This is my controller (user.php)

```html
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
        session_start();
        $this->load->model('usermodel');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html', 'date'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'javascript', 'form_validation', 'upload','email'));
        $this->load->database();
        $url  = base_url() . 'user';
        $this->smarty->assign('url', "$url");
}

public function loginValid() 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pswd', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $this->smarty->display('user/login.tpl');
        }   
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('usermodel');
            $res    = $this->usermodel->login();
            if ($res == "success") 
            {   
                $dataArray          = $this->usermodel->viewStatus();
                $notificationCount  = $this->usermodel->getNotification();

                $decode     = json_decode(json_encode($dataArray), TRUE);
                $getCount   = count(json_decode(json_encode($notificationCount),TRUE));
                $getName    = json_decode(json_encode($notificationCount),TRUE);

                $this->smarty->assign('count', $getCount );
                $this->smarty->assign('items', $decode);
                $this->smarty->assign('name', $getName);
                $this->smarty->assign('smsg', 'Login success');
                $this->smarty->display('user/home.tpl');
            } 
            else 
            {
                $this->smarty->assign('msg', 'Invalid username and password');
                $this->smarty->display('user/login.tpl');
            }
        }
    }

public function aboutView()
    {

        $dataArray  = $this->usermodel->aboutView();
        $decode     = json_decode(json_encode($dataArray),TRUE);
        $this->smarty->assign('items', $decode);
        $this->smarty->display('user/aboutview.tpl');
    }
```

This is my model "usermodel.php"

```html
<?php

class Usermodel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

 public function login() 
    {
        $username   = $this->input->post('username');
        $pswd       = $this->input->post('pswd');
        $this->db->select('username,userID');
        $data   = $this->db->get_where('users', array('userName' => $username, 'password' => $pswd))->row_array();
        if ($data) 
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return "success";
        }
        else 
            return "fail";
    }

 public function aboutView()
    {
        $id   = $this->session->userdata('userID');

        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('userID', $id);
        $query  = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

This is my view "aboutview.tpl"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/codeig_smarty/css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="coverPic">
            <img src="http://localhost/codeig_smarty/images/coverpicavatar.jpg" width="1259px" height="289px"/>
            <a href="http://localhost/codeig_smarty/index.php/user/fileUpload" class="profilePicLink">Upload new profile photo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="profilePic">
            <img src="http://localhost/codeig_smarty/images/avatar2.png" width="138px" height="163px"/>
            <a href="#" class="coverPicLink">Upload cover pic</a>
        </div>
        <div class="profileName"><p>{$items.0.fullName}</p></div>
        <div class="icons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$url}/displayMain">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="logout">
            <a href="http://localhost/codeig_smarty/index.php/user/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <span>About</span>
        </div>
        <div class="editabout">
            <span><a href="http://localhost/codeig_smarty/index.php/user/aboutEdit">Edit</a></span>
        </div>
         <form name="aboutviewform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="">
            <table class="abouttable" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Fullname:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.fullName}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.userName}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.email}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date of birth:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.dateofBirth}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gender:</th>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="male"/>Male
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Work:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.work}</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Company Name:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.companyName}</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Designation:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.designation}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Education:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.education}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country:</th>
                    <td><select name="country">
                            <option value="india">India</option>
                            <option value="usa">USA</option>
                            <option value="uk">UK</option>
                            <option value="uae">UAE</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>State:</th>
                    <td><select name="state">
                            <option value="kerala">Kerala</option>
                            <option value="karnataka">Karnataka</option>
                            <option value="tamilnadu">Tamilnadu</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Maritial status:</th>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="maritialstatus" value="unmarried" checked="unmarried"/>Unmarried
                        <input type="radio" name="maritialstatus" value="married"/>Married
                        <input type="radio" name="maritialstatus" value="divorced"/>Divorced
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Current Place:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.currentPlace}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contact number:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.contactNum}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>College:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.college}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Highschool:</th>
                    <td>{$items.0.highSchool}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Status:</th>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="status" value="{$items.0.status}" checked="active"/>Active
                        <input type="radio" name="status" value="{$items.0.status}"/>Inactive
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First remove `session_start()` function. You already have loaded session library. It is not good practice to mix CI sessions and PHP native sessions. Better way would be autoload that library since you need session across the application.

Comment: @Tpojka I removed `session_start()` function. Then also result is same

Comment: I assume that your user data is also cached and that file is served by the server. Once you refresh a new cache is generated and so you are getting correct values. Make sure you dont cache the user data seperately. I am not sure on CI, but in smarty we have tag as {nocache}user.name{/nocache}, so static contents are only cached and not dynamic contents.

Comment: How does logout method look? Are all data unset before looging next user?

Comment: @Tpojka Yeaa... all user data are unset on logout

Comment: I think the problem is in my Wamp server. When I run the code in another system, It works perfectly. Thankyou for your valuable information

Comment: if you echo `$this->session->userdata('userID')` in the controller(in function aboutView()), does it show the right data?